# Disappeared email alias in Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have set an email alias into my company domain's Gmail account. Recently (I don't know exactly when it stopped working) people started getting a "no such user" message from Google when using that alias.

At the domain registrar I have:

```
buday-rd.hu MX  10  aspmx.l.google.com      Elküldés
buday-rd.hu MX  20  alt1.aspmx.l.google.com Elküldés
buday-rd.hu MX  20  alt2.aspmx.l.google.com Elküldés
buday-rd.hu MX  30  aspmx2.googlemail.com   Elküldés
buday-rd.hu MX  30  aspmx3.googlemail.com   Elküldés
buday-rd.hu MX  30  aspmx4.googlemail.com   Elküldés
buday-rd.hu MX  30  aspmx5.googlemail.com   Elküldés
```

According to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125) this is fine by Google.

At last, I have found the aliases at user profile. Aliases for both of my domains are displayed but only for my main domain name the aliases are removable (Eltávolítás means Remove), so there is a problem with my secondary domain, `buday-rd.hu`.

```
nospam@buday-rd.hu
bnospam@buday-rd.hu
inospam@buday-rd.hu
mnospam@buday-rd.hu
bnospam@buday-rd.com - Eltávolítás
inospam@buday-rd.com - Eltávolítás
mnospam@buday-rd.com - Eltávolítás
```

Do you have any idea what could go wrong?

<sub>Google lists `buday-rd.hu` as a valid domain alias.</sub>